# Is this extended super-symmetry possible?

Tags: group-theory, supersymmetry, lie-algebra

The usual extended super-algebras have generators $Q_N^{\alpha},\overline{Q}_N^{\alpha}$ which can have $4^{N}$ components of the algebra. (Which can be arranged on the vertices of a hypercube). e.g. It can be got by associating each of the generators with a vector $(1,0,0,0,..)$ and the commutators can be got by adding these vectors.

But I was thinking about if it would be possible to make a supersymmetry algebra [out of the $E_8$ roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E8_(mathematics)). i.e. by associating the roots of $E_8$ with supersymmetry generators. If a root was a vector $A$ then the 'spin' of the generator would be perhaps $\frac{1}{2}\sum_i A - 1$.

We would assign the roots permutations of $A=(+\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2})$ to make 8 generators $Q_A^{\alpha}$. And then all the other elements of the algebra would be got by (anti-)commutators of $Q_A^{\alpha}$, and the resulting operator would be placed on the root that is the sum/difference of those previous roots. In that way we could associate every root of $E_8$ with a supersymmetry generator. 240 in all. Plus we would need an extra 8 to complete $E_8$. However there would be 128 fermionic generators and 120 bosonic generators so not sure if this violates some principle.

For example $\{Q_A,Q_{B}\}=Z_{A-B}$ where $A-B = (1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0)$ and permutations is the 56 roots of $SU(8)$. And so on, so that combining the generators would be equivalent to adding the roots.

This would mean that the resulting algebra would be like lie-algebra $E_8$ except the spin(16) section of the operators would be anti-commuting instead of commuting.

The idea of this comes from the obvious similarities between the $E_8$ lie algebra [(see Constructions)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E8_(mathematics)) and the supersymmetry algebra. So I wonder if there is a simple argument to say if this would work or not?

(Or perhaps this would just be equivalent to the $N=8$ supersymmetry except with 8 operators missing?)

In mathematical terms I suppose you might call this a $Z_2$ grading of $E_8$ where the grading is given by the sum of the root coordinates mod 2?